# Passing data with getIntent().getStringExtra() and is returning null in the other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code in ForgetPassword activity which I want to pass the DB userID to the next activity (SetNewPassword)

```
public void verifyPhoneNumber(View view) {
        if (!validatePhoneNumber())  return;

        String userEnteredPhoneNumber = Phone.getText().toString();

        // Checks if the user is in the database
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        Query checkUser = ref.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(userEnteredPhoneNumber);
        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    Phone.setError(null);
                    int userId = -1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= snapshot.getChildrenCount(); i++) {
                        if (userEnteredPhoneNumber.equals(snapshot.child(String.valueOf(i)).child("phoneNumber").getValue())) {
                            userId = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String phoneFromDB = snapshot.child(String.valueOf(userId)).child("phoneNumber").getValue(String.class);
                    if  (phoneFromDB.equals(userEnteredPhoneNumber)) {
                        Phone.setError(null);
                        // Send to next view
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, SetNewPassword.class);
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", userEnteredPhoneNumber);
                        intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                        intent.putExtra("whatToDo", "updateData");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Phone.setError("The entered phone number doesn't exist!");
                    Phone.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the code I have on SetNewPassword activity, strangely I can pass the phoneNumber but not the ID which is null, I don't get it why... I need to get the ID to update the user's password

```
public void changePassword(View view) {
        if (!validatePassword() | !validateConfirmPassword())
            return;

        // Get data from fields
        String _newPassword = newPassword.getText().toString();
        String _phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
        String getId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");

        // Update Data in FB
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        ref.child(getId).child("password").setValue(_newPassword);
        
        // Call next screen
        //Intent intent = new Intent(SetNewPassword.this, ForgetPasswordSucessMessage.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that userId isn't null in the verifyPhoneNumber method?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `userEnteredPhoneNumber` is a String and `userId` is defined as an int so you can only use `getStringExtra()` with the first one.

To fix it either pass the userId as string ( `toString()` ):

```
intent.putExtra(USER_ID, userId.toString());
```

OR get it as an integer ( `getIntExtra()` ):

```
int getId = getIntent().getIntExtra(USER_ID, 0);
```

I prefer the second option because I guess you don't need the userId as string in that second activity.

I would suggest you using constants when passing and retrieving the parameters instead of writing the string in each activity. By using constants is easier to prevent mistakes.

Comment: Thanks alot! Noob mistake ahaha